# UISlider value changed not firing

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uislider

I have a UISlider object in a class like this:

```
class SliderObject {
  // Other properties
  @IBOutlet weak var slider: UISlider!
  @IBAction func valChange(_ sender: Any) {
    // Not called
  }

  func getView() -> UIView {
    // Return a UIView with the slider in it - the slider is in a nib
    return Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("SliderObjectNib", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! UIView
  }
}

// In some other View Controller
var s: SliderObject? // <---- This is the solution.. Keep a strong reference to the variable so it won't get released after `viewDidLoad` returns
func viewDidLoad() {
  s = SliderObject()
  self.view.addSubView(s.getView())
}
```

Everything renders fine. I can see and interact with the slider on my View Controller, but the `valChange` function never gets called when I scrub the slider... Any thought?

Comment: please show getView implementation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling a method from one class to another. This reference is created in a local variable  will be released when that method exits. It attempts to call the function on the invalid object.
Use delegate - Define a protocol for the method and have your view controller implement that protocol. You can then pass the view controller to the method.

Comment: This actually makes sense. I want to encapsulate the slider logic in the SliderObject. What you said about implementing a delegate in my VC makes sense, but is there a way around that?

Comment: Found the answer: If I keep a strong reference of the `SliderObject` in my VC, it works! Thanks for pointing this out. If you have a more elegant solution, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 2):

Add below code:-

```
// As the slider moves it will continuously call the -valChange:
slider.continuous = true; // false makes it call only once you let go
slider.addTarget(self, action: "valChange:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
```

Comment: Yeah tried that too... No dice.. Problem is it's not getting called at all, once let go or continuously..

Comment: can you share the getView Implementation?

Comment: Updated - I implemented the slider in a nib.

Comment: Is your slider the top most element in the view Hierarchy? Need to look at how your view hierarchy is in the nib?

Comment: Yes, I can scrub it.

Comment: cool..so your ValueChanged action IBAction is linked in the nib?